# Callback function when a node is created/destroyed

Tags: ros, callback, shutdown, rosgraph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am developing a parallel solution with ROS, and I want to develop a node that executes certain functions when a another node in the architecture is added or destroyed at runtime. I know that I can do some status polling with rosgraph library, but is there any way to have a callback function when any of the other nodes execute ros::init or ros::shutdown?

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64764/callback-function-when-a-node-is-created/destroyed/) by [Javier J. Salmerón García](https://answers.ros.org/users/4037/javier-j.-salmer%C3%B3n-garc%C3%ADa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like an application for the [bond package](http://ros.org/wiki/bond).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Javier J. Salmerón García](https://answers.ros.org/users/4037/javier-j.-salmer%C3%B3n-garc%C3%ADa/) on 2013-06-12**:
Thank you, with this library I can know when a certain node finishes. Any ideas of how to detect that a new node has been created?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-12**:
I suppose it could announce itself on a topic, when ready to run.